# How to perform harmonic balancing on a 2nd order linear differential equation with time-varying coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis, control-theory

**The Problem**

I currently have the following equation, which I would like to solve using harmonic balancing.

$$\left[\mathbf M_c + \mathbf M_v(\mathbf \Theta)\right]\ddot{\mathbf \Theta} + \mathbf C\dot{\mathbf \Theta} + \left[\mathbf K + \mathbf G(\mathbf \Theta) \right]\mathbf \Theta = \mathbf F(\mathbf \Theta) \tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf M_c$, $\mathbf M_v$, and $\mathbf G$ are all diagonal matrices, and the elements of the latter two are sinusoidal functions.

However, when I compare the results of the harmonic balancing solution with the typical time-domain solution, they are significantly different.

I can get the two solutions to match when I have an equation similar to Eq. 1 above, but without the $\mathbf M_v$ and $\mathbf G$ terms, so that shows me that I have at least some part of the process right. Thus things go wrong when I introduce the variable coefficients $\mathbf M_v$ and $\mathbf G$.

---

**My Attempt**

Let us first define the Fourier series in exponential form for the following terms:

$$\mathbf \Theta = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty}\theta_n e^{in\omega t}, \quad \mathbf F = \sum^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty}\mathbf f_n e^{in\omega t}, \quad \mathbf M_v = \sum^{+\infty}_{k=-\infty}\mathbf m_ke^{ik\omega t}, \quad \mathbf G=\sum^{+\infty}_{k=-\infty}\mathbf g_ke^{ik\omega t}$$

Substituting the above into Eq. 1 I get:

\begin{equation}
\left[\mathbf M_c + \sum_k\mathbf m_ke^{ik\omega t} \right]\sum_n (-n\omega)^2\theta_n e^{in\omega t} + \mathbf C\sum_n(in\omega)\theta_ne^{in\omega t} \\ 
+\left[\mathbf K + \sum_k\mathbf g_ke^{ik\omega t}\right]\sum_n\theta_ne^{in\omega t} = \sum_n\mathbf f_n e^{in\omega t}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

Simplifying the above I get:

\begin{equation}
\sum_n\sum_k \left[\mathbf g_k -(n\omega)^2\mathbf m_k\right]\theta_ne^{i(k+n)\omega t} + \\ \sum_n\left[in\omega\mathbf C - (n\omega)^2\mathbf M_c + \mathbf K \right]\theta_ne^{in\omega t} = \sum_n\mathbf f_n e^{in\omega t} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

So by considering the positive indices of the sums, I turn the above into a matrix of linear equations, by trying to find a common value for the exponential function of all terms, such that it cancels out: e.g. if the exponential with $n$ by itself is equal to 3, then the exponential with $n+k$ means that $n=1,2$ when $k=2,1$:

\begin{align}
&\left[i\omega\mathbf C - (\omega)^2\mathbf M_v + \mathbf K\right]\theta_1 = \mathbf f_1\\
&\left[2i\omega\mathbf C - (2\omega)^2\mathbf M_v + \mathbf K\right]\theta_2 + \left[\mathbf g_1 - (\omega)^2\mathbf m_1\right]\theta_1 = \mathbf f_2 \\
&\left[3i\omega\mathbf C - (3\omega)^2\mathbf M_v + \mathbf K\right]\theta_3 + \left[\mathbf g_2 - (\omega)^2\mathbf m_2\right]\theta_1 + \left[\mathbf g_1 - (2\omega)^2\mathbf m_1\right]\theta_2 = \mathbf f_3 \\
&\quad \vdots
\end{align}

Then I can turn the above into a matrix:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf A_{1,1} \\
\left[\mathbf g_1 - (\omega)^2\mathbf m_1\right] & \mathbf A_{2,2} \\
\left[\mathbf g_2 - (\omega)^2\mathbf m_2\right]& \left[\mathbf g_1 - (2\omega)^2\mathbf m_1\right] & \mathbf A_{3,3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\theta_1 \\ \theta_2 \\ \theta_3 \\ \vdots
\end{bmatrix}=
%
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf f_1 \\ \mathbf f_2 \\ \mathbf f_3 \\ \vdots
\end{bmatrix} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

where for rows with index $r$ and columns with index $c$ we have:

\begin{gather}
\mathbf A_{r,r=c}=ir\omega\mathbf C - (r\omega)^2\mathbf M_v + \mathbf K \\
A_{r, c<r} = \mathbf g_{r-c} - (c\omega)^2\mathbf m_{r-c}
\end{gather}

where the above is a diagonal matrix since functions $\mathbf M_v$ and $\mathbf G$ are also diagonal.

Having solved Eq. 4 to obtain the coefficients $\theta_n$ for the positive part of the sum, the conversion back to the time domain can be done as follows:

$$\mathbf\Theta(t) = \sum^{N}_{n=1} 2|\theta_n|\cos(n\omega t - \phi_n)$$

where $\phi_n = \text{arg}(\bar{\theta}_n)$, where $\bar{\theta}_n$ is the conjugate of $\theta_n$.